# Can MonoDevelop (2.2b2) running on Windows use the Microsoft compilers?

Tags: windows, vb.net, monodevelop, vbc

I've installed MonoDevelop 2.2b2 on my Windows workstation, which has the .NET 3.5 SDK installed and running fine (I can use VS Express and command-line compilation without a problem).

Apparently MonoDevelop defaults to calling the Mono VB.NET compiler (vbcnc.exe) rather than the Microsoft compiler (vbc.exe) when building a project. (I haven't tried a C# project yet.)

Is there a way to tell MonoDevelop to use the standard VB.NET compiler for .NET 3.5? I can't seem to find such an option anywhere in the application, solution, or project options.

I like the MonoDevelop IDE (even better than SharpDevelop), but I'm not sold on installing and using Mono's compiler just yet, nor do I know if it can even handle the latest VB.NET / C# language features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MonoDevelop does already use Microsoft's Visual Basic compiler. In fact, MonoDevelop/Win32 runs on top of MS.NET, not on top of Mono. If you have Mono installed (it is a separate installer), then you'll have the choice to build with MS.NET or with Mono.

Comment: Lluis, I've looked all over the place for such a choice. When I click Build, MonoDevelop tries to use vbcnc.exe, the Mono VB.NET compiler (which is not installed) rather than MS's vbc.exe.

Answer (score -1):

Isn't MonoDevelop a subset of Visual Studio Express? Why not use the free express versions?

Comment: No, MonoDevelop is a standalone IDE from the Mono Project to allow cross platform development on Mono.

Comment: No, it's a completely separate product with a feature set that is similar to VS Express but not the same. The VS Express 2008 products do not meet my needs and VS2010 beta on my dual-core 2GHz machine is slower than QBasic on my old 8088, so I'm evaluating MonoDevelop.

Comment: when I said subset, I didn't mean there was a commercial relationship between the products - I just meant tht monodevelop is less powerful than vsexpress.